# Simulating datasets in R for model selection

Tags: r, machine-learning, simulation

I made a code to simulate a dataset in R to see how backward selection works in machine learning. And I generated poly() function to write polynomial function and then wanted to choose the suitable polynomial using Cp, BIC, adjusted R^2.

The code is:

```
 ###Generating dataset
 set.seed(1)
 X = rnorm(100)
 eps = rnorm(100)

 beta0 = 3
 beta1 = 2
 beta2 = -3
 beta3 = 0.3
 Y = beta0 + beta1 * X + beta2 * X^2 + beta3 * X^3 + eps
 
library(leaps)
data.full = data.frame(y = Y, x = X)
mod.full = regsubsets(y ~ poly(x, 10, raw = T), data = data.full, nvmax = 10)
mod.summary = summary(mod.full)

### Find the model size for best cp, BIC and adjr2
which.min(mod.summary$cp)
```

For cp, BIC and adjusted R^2 I get model with polynomial 3 as it should be

However, now I want to simulate 100 datasets and see in how many datasets do I get the right model. I simulated 100 datasets but now I am not getting polynomial 3 for each of the measures. And I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong. My code for simulation is:

```
###Generating 100 datasets
data <- replicate(100, rnorm(n=100))
epsilon <- replicate(100,rnorm(n=100))

###Formula (same as before)
 Y = beta0 + beta1 * data + beta2 * data^2 + beta3 * data^3 + epsilon
 data.full = data.frame(y = Y, x = data)

 ###Using polynomial terms
 mod.bwd = regsubsets(data.full$y.1 ~ poly(data.full$x.1, 10, raw = T), data = data.full, nvmax = 10, 
method = "backward")
bwd.summary = summary(mod.bwd)

which.min(bwd.summary$cp)
which.min(bwd.summary$bic)
which.max(bwd.summary$adjr2)
```

For a given subset cp, Bic, adjr2 are giving me different results. For example, using y.1 and x.1 (first dataset in simulation) gives following results:

> which.min(bwd.summary$cp): 7
>
> which.min(bwd.summary$bic): 4
>
> which.max(bwd.summary$adjr2): 9

Can someone help me what I'm doing wrong in simulating these 100 datasets.

Comment: You are not *necessarily* doing something wrong; there is absolutely no reason *in principle* why different criteria should suggest the same model - otherwise we would not need all these different criteria in the first place, and we could just do with a single one...

Comment: But when I just make single dataset with 100 observations, all there criteria give me polynomial 3 to be the best one. Shouldn't at least one dataset should be where all three criteria should give polynomial 3 to be the best one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've read your code correctly you run the model on the same simulated dataset 100 times instead of all 100 simulated datasets, this should do the trick:

```
set.seed(42)

###Generating 100 datasets
data <- replicate(100, rnorm(n=100))
epsilon <- replicate(100,rnorm(n=100))

###Formula (same as before)
 Y = beta0 + beta1 * data + beta2 * data^2 + beta3 * data^3 + epsilon
 data.full = data.frame(y = Y, x = data)


res <- lapply(1:100, function(i){
 ###Using polynomial terms
 mod.bwd = regsubsets(data.full[[i]] ~ poly(data.full[[100+i]], 10, raw = T), data = data.full, nvmax = 10, 
method = "backward")
bwd.summary = summary(mod.bwd)

c(
which.min(bwd.summary$cp),
which.min(bwd.summary$bic),
which.max(bwd.summary$adjr2)
)
})

res <- do.call(rbind, res)
```

With this rng-seed this gives some lines where all cirteria select the correct model.